# Error building Plotly Dash (npm run build)

Tags: python, python-3.x, npm, plotly-dash

I really want to contribute to Plotly Dash, following the contribution steps on (https://github.com/plotly/dash), and have an issue while building it on Windows 10/Python3.8.

Here are the commands what I ran during the process.

```
   1 python -m venv .venv/dev
   2 .venv\dev\scripts\activate
   3 pip install -e .[testing,dev]
   4 npm install
   5 npm run build
```

5th step showed me the following error.

```
> npm run build

> dash@ build E:\python\dash
> run-s private::build.*


> dash@ private::build.components E:\python\dash
> python dash/development/update_components.py 'all'

lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter including "*@('all')*"
lerna info filter [ "*@('all')*" ]
lerna ERR! EFILTER No packages remain after filtering [ "*@('all')*" ]

Failed installing npm dependencies for the following component packages 'all' (status=1)
lerna notice cli v4.0.0
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter including "*@('all')*"
lerna info filter [ "*@('all')*" ]
lerna ERR! EFILTER No packages remain after filtering [ "*@('all')*" ]

 Finished updating the following component packages 'all' (status=1) 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dash@ private::build.components: `python dash/development/update_components.py 'all'`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dash@ private::build.components script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-28T03_50_37_219Z-debug.log
ERROR: "private::build.components" exited with 1.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! dash@ build: `run-s private::build.*`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the dash@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-28T03_50_37_305Z-debug.log
```

Seems the error comes from the update_components.py, but not sure what's wrong.

```
>python dash/development/update_components.py all
```

> 'dash-html-components' is not recognized as an internal or external
> command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Failed installing npm dependencies for the following component
> packages dash-core-components|dash-html-components|dash-table
> (status=255) 'dash-html-components' is not recognized as an internal
> or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Finished updating the following component packages
> dash-core-components|dash-html-components|dash -table (status=255)

Any help or advice would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Seems like a bug on Windows. I also tested on Linux and it works there. I would file an issue. From messing around it seems like part of the problem is the way `'all'` is interpreted in the `private::build.components` command on Windows. I've tried replacing `'all'` with `\"all\"` and that seems to work better, but I still couldn't get it to run all the way. The value of the cmd string in `dash/development/update_components.py` seems to be the problem.

Comment: Right. update_components.py is problem. Just append error from the script.